# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-api-apps

I have developed a backend app using azure api app. When i use swagger to test my app everything works fine. on the other hand i have a web app client (asp.net core).In the front end i use angularjs for crud operations. When i try to perform the same job i get an error `"exceptionMessage":"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.","exceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","stackTrace":"`
Why is my web client is causing this error in the back end. I have searched my backend there no parckage reference for version=3.0.0.0 im using version 3.3.8. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: According to your description, we couldn't repro your issue. I guess maybe there are some other package need use the Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure 3.0.0.0 not 3.3.8. So you will face this error. I suggest you could try to install the 3.0.0 instead of the 3.3.8. If this operation doesn't solved your issue. I suggest you could post all of your package.config file content. Then we could repro your issue and find the solution.

Comment: I figured it out, my backend was referencing the clientruntinme without components installed, so i removed the reference and everything is back on line